# .Net - interop assemblies taking 15 seconds to load when being referenced in a function

Tags: c#, .net, com-interop

This is a C# console application. I have a function that does something like this:

```
static void foo()
{
       Application powerpointApp;
       Presentation presentation = null;

       powerpointApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.ApplicationClass();
}
```

That's all it does. When it is called there is a fifteen second delay before the function gets hit. I added something like this:

```
static void MyAssemblyLoadEventHandler(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
{
       Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " ASSEMBLY LOADED: " + args.LoadedAssembly.FullName);
       Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This gets fired telling me that my interop assemblies have been loaded about 10 milliseconds before my foo function gets hit. What can I do about this? The program needs to call this function (and eventually do something else) once and then exit so I need for these assemblies to be cached or something. Ideas?

Comment: Does it also take 15 seconds if you manually start PowerPoint (as a regular application)?

Comment: Nope. It comes right up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be the certificate revocation list - the time-out on this is 15 seconds.
Is there anything in the event log? Can you check if any network connections are happening during the time-out?

[I blogged some details about certificate revocation delay](http://blogs.conchango.com/anthonysteele/archive/2007/02/07/Delay-when-starting-up-a-web-service.aspx) a while ago. Follow the link, I won't cut and paste it here.

Comment: This was a very good suggestion. I was noticing a connection that was timing out when the assembly was loading.

Answer (score 3):

15 seconds sounds like a timeout to me.  Are you signing your assemblies?  We had a problem where the framework wants to check the certificate revocation list when loading, but fails after 15 secs.

HTH

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but it is probably the time for PowerPoint to start up after the interop assemblies have loaded.

Comment: It launches instantly after the assemblies are loaded. The function doesn't even get hit until they get loaded.

Comment: try monitor with your taskmanager, so you call that function, if ppowerpoint.exe is loaded at that point, it could be delayed due to that

Answer (score 0):

If method foo() is not called upon application start and you have some other tasks to do before it is called, you can start a separate thread in the beginning to load the assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

```
<runtime>

   <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>

</runtime>
```

See here for details

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx

"We recommend that services use the  element to improve startup performance. Using this element can also help avoid delays that can cause a time-out and the cancellation of the service startup."